# Bulbs in parallel/series (very basic)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

I need some help understanding very basic circuit concepts, specifically for the question in the image below.

So from what I know is that in a series setup: voltage is divided over the components, current stays the same. In a parallel setup: voltage is the same in all branches, current is divided between the branches.

However the answers for this question are: final current in lamp is halved in series, final current is the same in parallel.

[image]

Comment: I note that the question has a little twist to it, which I'll bet is unintentional ... I doubt this crossed the mind of whomever wrote it.  We are not explicitly told what source of power is.  At the extremes, it could be an ideal voltage source *or* and ideal current source.  And, of course, anything in between.  If it's a current source, the answer is the exact opposite of the "correct" answer.  However, we are safe in inferring that a voltage source was intended by the shape of the $I$ vs $t$ plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With two lamps in series you will get double overall resistance, thus of Ohm's law overall current is I = U / (2R) that means overall current gets half of one-lamp case with I = U / R. As you said, this current is the same in the both lamps and voltage on each of the lamps gets half of the overall.

In parallel you have two lamps attached to one the same voltage so you can consider them as two independent parallel circuits. Each lamp has original voltage that means each would pass the same current as in original one-lamp case: I = U / R. This is current through each lamp. *If you asked (maybe next time) about overall current through the both lamps together in parallel then you will sum both lamps currents then get overall current doubled to the original one-lamp case.*  Voltage in parallel stays the same as original if both lamps are attached to the same terminals.

Comment: oh of course, the resistance get doubled with two bulbs, silly of me.

thanks!